# Warning: missing space before text for line 20 of jade file

Tags: pug

I get `Warning: missing space before text for line 20 of jade file` for this code:

Any ideas?

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="fooApp")
    head
        title Foo
        script(language='javascript', src='bower_components/angular/angular.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(language='javascript', src='bower_components/requirejs/require.js', type='text/javascript', data-main='js/Main.js')
        script(language='javascript', src='http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js', type='text/javascript')
        script(language='javascript', src='bower_components/platform/platform.js', type='text/javascript')
        //link(rel="import", href="elements/elements.html" )
        link(rel="import", href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" )
        link(rel="import", href="bower_components/core-component-page/core-component-page.html" )



        link(rel='import', href='core-scaffold.html')
        link(rel='import', href='../core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html')
        link(rel='import', href='../core-menu/core-menu.html')
        link(rel='import', href='../core-item/core-item.html')
        style
            html, body {            <-- line 20
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `style` to `style.`.
My guess is that Jade tries to parse your CSS rule, and does not understand it, as it is something written for the browser and not for the template engine.

Adding a dot `.` will tell Jade to render the following block of text "as is", and to not try to parse it.

You can read more about it on [Jade reference](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/).
Hope that helps.

Comment: You're welcome @FutuToad :) It does not *need* to be an external CSS file as far as Jade is concerned. I guess seeing a `.` makes it happy, it saves him the pain of trying to figure out what you were trying to do. But regarding code conventions (reusability...), being developer-friendly etc..., yes it *should* be an external CSS file.