# Warning: missing space before text for line 2 of jade file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug, linemanjs

> I already checked these links before posting my questions but none
>   suffice to my case.

Link 1 - [Warning: missing space before text for line 20 of jade file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25124621/1594368)

Link 2 - [Jade - missing space before text for line x of jade file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22181813/1594368)

Following is the error I am getting -

[image: Jade Template]

Now my Jade.js file contains following text - http://pastebin.com/gEytRnuE

Issue is I don't have `anything at line 2` still its prompting error at Line 2.

FYI - I am using `LinemanJS` for my front end management tasks for the app.

Comment: In the Pastebin version, there's a space on line 2 — Since spaces *can* have special meaning in Jade that might be the problem.